Command Failed: Is a directory
Trying to run PyQtDesigner through VSC and failed.
I was trying to use PyQt Designer through VSC's PyqT Integrator and sent the QTDesigner path as such:
/Users/atillayildirim/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/qt-main-5.15.2-h719ae48_7/bin/Designer.app
Homever, when I try to use PYQT: NEW FORM this error appears:
Error: Command failed: "/Users/atillayildirim/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/qt-main-5.15.2-h719ae48_7/bin/Designer.app"
/bin/sh: /Users/atillayildirim/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/qt-main-5.15.2-h719ae48_7/bin/Designer.app: is a directory


If Designere.app is a MacOS application then it will be treated as a directory in terminal.You may want to dive deeper into the package and find the file you need.

Are you on macOS? .app is a macOS "executable." I put that in quotes because as it says here, .app files are actually packages that contain a bunch of stuff, including the executable itself.
Inside of the .app package, there is a MacOS directory that should contain the executable so you will need to look there to find the file that VSCode needs to run.
